# Watch on a new attribute which is attached on a nested objects, but not firing

Tags: angularjs

How could I watch on a new attribute which is attached on a nested objects.

As you can see, each row of the table is an item of fares array.

And I manually add a field `order_amount` to each fare

```
<td class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
  <h4>
  <input ng-model="fare.order_amount" type="number" min="0" ng-init="fare.order_amount=0">
  </h4>
</td>
```

Once a user change the order amount, the shopping cart should be updated immediately.

However, the whole model is complicated. All fares are belongs_to `flight_list`

```
    $scope.$watchCollection('flight_list', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log($scope);
    });
```

So I watched on flight_list collection, but it didn't fire, when I increase the `order amount`.

Furthermore, there are about 500 fares on each page.

I'm afraid that the performance will be really poor.

Any good idea?

[image: inline]

[
  {

```
"from_airport": {
  "id": 11,
  "city_id": 7,
  "code": "TPE",
  "name": "桃園國際機場",
  "created_at": "2016-07-06T18:19:11.483Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-07-06T18:19:11.483Z"
},

"fares": [
  {
    "id": 5241,
    "flight_sku_id": 1311,
    "cabin_class": "ECONOMY",
    "price": 15038.0,
    "specs": {
      "flight_number": "IT-911",
      "duration": 7,
      "return_departure_time": "06:00",
      "return_arrive_time": "13:00"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-07-06T18:20:14.292Z",
    "updated_at": "2016-07-06T18:20:14.292Z",
    "cabin_code": "J",
    "eligibility": "ADULT",
    "description": null,
    "ticket_type": "GROUP",
    "saleable": true,
    "cost": 14345.0
  },

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set 3rd argument to true for deep watching a collection

```
$scope.$watchCollection('flight_list', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log($scope);
}, true);
```

Comment: it didn't work. The field is dynamically  added to the model dynamically, is it the reason to cause the problem?